# Dynamically choose class from string - "MyClassName" -> MyClassName

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I use babel.js traspiler to write ES6 code.

I have a string containing class name. I want a class that I can instantiate. How?

I tried:

```
eval("MyClassName") -> :(
window["MyClassName"] -> :(
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What module system are you using with Babel? By default it's common JS, so anything [on this page](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/modules/#common-default-) would work.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you want to do this? Depending on the usecase, there may be options, but overall, as you've seen, the answer is no, without `eval`.

Comment: Can you stuff the classes you might want to do it with into an object ahead of time? Is the class you want to do it with a named export of some module?

Comment: Actually `eval` should work as long as the class is in scope.

Comment: Upvote for `-> :(` :)))

Answer (score 3):

**You Can:**

Since with BabelJS you have to transpile to an ES5 module loader, it would be as simple as (depending on the [module format](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/modules/#common-default-) you've specified at transpile time):

```
const MyClassName = require("MyClassName");
const obj = new MyClassName();
```

However this is *not ES6*, but transpiled ES5. So your code will not work in true ES6 environments.

In an ES6 environment a `class` is just syntactic sugar for a function, so there is no reason you cannot do:

```
// Class definition
class MyClassName { }
// Pollute global scope
(global || window).MyClassName = MyClassName;
```

And load it like so:

```
const instance = new (window || global)["MyClassName"]();
```

But in doing so you've just broken the major feature modules give you in the first place.

**You Should:**

Create a *factory* class. In the majority of cases, the amount of classes you can instantiate is finite. You should create a factory function which gives you a class instance based on a string:

```
import MyClassName from "./MyClassName"
class MyFactory {
    static getInstance(value) {
        if(value === "MyClassName") {
            return new MyClassName();
        }
        throw new Error(`Could not instantiate ${value}`);
    }
}
```

Which would be used as:

```
import MyFactory from "./MyFactory";
const instance = MyFactory.getInstance("MyClassName");
```

Obviously you could expand on that to use a `Map` instead of a string of `if` statements, but you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks for that! Very thoughtful response.

I just googled the same thing, and I found this thread (classic) and just realized I did not see your notice. I am having a look at the same piece of code that I do not like. This is what you described in "You Should".

Well, I'll keep adding to the factory class.

Comment: Is there a reason why the factory should be a class? Could I not just use a factory function?

Comment: No reason at all. Looking back at this answer I wouldn't choose class syntax here myself now. A regular function would work just as well.